# Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, api, авторизация, passport

Занимаюсь разработкой `API` на `Laravel` для мобильного приложения и решил использовать Passport для авторизации. Не совсем разобрался в некоторых моментах.

1. Как я понял, `Passport` реализует `OAuth` сервер. Он же предоставляет интерфейс на `Vue.js` для создания клиентов и выдачи токенов. Но вот не совсем понятно, кто эти пользователи, которые будут создавать OAuth клиентов и пользоваться интерфейсом. Это администраторы ресурса или же реальные пользователи мобильного приложения?
2. Кем должно выступать моё API - сторонним клиентом `Passport'a` или же это один ресурс? Обратил внимание, что во многих туториалах люди реализуют `Passport` рядом с `API`. Нормально ли это?

Конечная цель чего я хочу достичь - это создать систему авторизации через `API`, не смешивая `Web` составляющую, а большинство маршрутов `Passport'a` имеют `web,auth` мидлверы.

Буду благодарен за советы.

Answer (score 0):

> создать систему авторизации через API, не смешивая Web составляющую, а большинство маршрутов Passport'a имеют web,auth мидлверы.

У Вас проблемы с пониманием протокола OAuth. Он наоборот редиректит пользователя на форму авторизации(web) родительского сервиса и ввод личных данных происходит там, а не в сторонних приложениях. Затем отдает токены, с которыми можно получать доступ.

Если Ваше приложение напрямую запрашивает авторизационные данные у клиента попробуйте так https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51
(Bearer Auth)